# Search for Outlook contacts in multiple categories - AND not OR

Tags: contacts, categories, outlook-2010

The environment is Outlook 2010 connected to an Exchange server.

The contacts are in a public folder.

I want to find the contacts that are categorized as "Education AND Events".

Using advanced search I can find the contacts that are categorized as "Education OR Events" but this is not useful to me.

I know I can export the list to an Excel spreadsheet and do it manually but this feature is needed for common users and done constantly.

Any idea on how to do it will be most welcome.

Thanks,

Hanan Cohen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

:)
I have the same issue, only I wanted Outlook to show me contacts with a category, but not another category. So, there's a way to do that, just found that out. If you go to the search field and write the following:

**category:="Education"+"Events"**

It should show you the contacts that are under **Education** AND **Events** categories together. :-) If you want to have contacts that have **Education** but NOT **Events**, then you replace the plus sign with a minus sign, and it should do the job.

This is kind of a hidden search mechanism for Outlook 2010, I don't know if it will work in older versions of Outlook, but I just found it out and I was so very happy!!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was useful, but not totally correct, at least not in Outlook 2013.
There you should write in the search field: **category:="Education"+category:"Events"**
(in my language, Dutch, in Dutch Outlook, f.e.: categorie:="Energie"+categorie:"Armoede")